# Laravel 5.8 running on PHP 8.0

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have issue now

```
Updating dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                     
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  Problem 1                                                                                                                                                                                               
    - laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.                                                                        
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
```

I tried add this already

```
"php": "^7.1.3|^8.0",
```

What do I do now? I upgraded my local PHP to 8.0 today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3` - that is a pretty clear statement. Laravel 5.8 has seen its last update in April 2020, PHP 8 has been released in December 2020, so it looks pretty obvious to me that 5.8 cannot support PHP 8.

You have two options: stick to PHP 7 and Laravel 5.8, or update Laravel to any later version. The second one looks better to me, as even the security support for 5.8 has [ended more than a year ago](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases#support-policy)

Comment: @AndrewFox what makes you think that Laravel 5.1 won't work with MySQL 8?

Comment: @NicoHasse my mistake, for some reason I thought you said Laravel 5.8 wouldn't work with MySql 8, but I'm wrong. I've deleted my comment.