# How Can I use php 8 for my laravel 5* project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, environment, php-8

Is there any way to use php 8 or hiugher for my laravel 5* project. Please suggest.

I don't want to increase my laravel version but php.

Comment: There is no way. You would have to port Laravel 5.x to PHP8 yourself. [Laravel 5.8 running on PHP 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321058/laravel-5-8-running-on-php-8-0)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Laravel 5.x is compatible with PHP 7.x. If you want to use PHP 8.x you must upgrade your Laravel project.

Here you have the link to check Laravel 5.x requirements:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#server-requirements

And here is the Laravel 8 and Laravel 9 server requirements:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#php-8
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#php-7.3.0-required

Also here is a package for a fast Laravel upgrade process. :)
https://laravelshift.com/